# After updating to Blender 2.68 Driver Scripts are no longer automatically excecuted

Tags: customization

When loading a .blend file the console window shows error messages like:

```
skipping driver 'x1*(1-x2)', automatic scripts are disabled
skipping driver 'x1*(1-x2*x3)', automatic scripts are disabled
skipping driver 'x1*(1-x2)', automatic scripts are disabled
skipping driver 'x1*(1-x2*x3)', automatic scripts are disabled
```

In the file browser the option Trusted Source can be set but isn't remembered when using *File: Open Recent*

[image]

Can the new security features switched off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn this setting off in the user preferences by unchecking *Auto Run Python Scripts*:

[image]

See the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Security) for more information.