# Counter rotate Animation using Driver

Tags: rigging, transforms

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtWcpUedQhM):

I created a sphere and parented it to the empty axes
Empty_axes is parented to the empty_cube
I added a drive to the empty_axes to counter the rotation of the empty_cube(such that sphere will be at the same rotation angle in global space).

But it is not working as It should be. Empty axes are moving along with the cube.
Here are the screenshots of what I have done.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I got to know what the problem is ..
Its explained here
https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=498&aid=35971&group_id=9

Comment: The header from the screenshots clearly says driver is disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/after-updating-to-blender-2-68-driver-scripts-are-no-longer-automatically-excecu ?

Comment: @ideasman42 Yeah, I saw it later on, that's how I got to know what my problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the thread posted in your comment  Campbell Barton clearly states that you need to enable auto-execution. 
You find the option in the *User Preferences Dialog*

[image]