# Why does my PyDriver only update on frame-change?

Tags: python

I have created a driver using this expression:
`bpy.data.objects["e1"].location.x**2/5`

It works whenever I change the frame but I'd like it to work on redraw. One solution that won't always be appropriate is to select the driven object along with the driving object. Is there a more universal solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `bpy.data.***` because blender won't know to create a dependancy between the objects (this is why updates are not working properly),

Instead:

- add a driver variable with the button `Add Variable`.
- select object ID type.
- then enter "e1" as the object name.
- the location channels X axis are default.

[image]

Now you can use the variable name defined by the driver variable in place of: `bpy.data.objects["e1"].location.x`.

Comment: I added a screenshot because the syntax of the path wasn't clear to me. Other than that it worked like a charm (:

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this (building on [ideasman42's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2790/372)) would be to forsake Python altogether and use a couple different aspects of the driver interface: the polynomial generator and the transform channel option.

### Why?

- **Python is [not automatically enabled anymore](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1903/372).** Your blendfile must be opened as "trusted" for any Python drivers or scripts to run.
- **It's more elegant.** There's no need to use Python when all you want to do is a bit of math. This also makes it more legible (someone who doesn't know Python might have no idea what `var**2/5` does), easier to maintain (there's a nice GUI interface instead of having to modify a scriptlet), and more flexible (you could easily change this to a cubic, quartic, etc. equation just by entering the coefficients; `var**5/3+var**4*0.34-var**3/2+...` doesn't look nearly as nice).
- **It could be faster.** I don't know how or if the driver system optimizes the driver instructions, but it's [certainly more likely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582356/fastest-way-of-finding-the-middle-value-of-a-triple#comment1444816_1582524) that an explicitly specified arithmetic expression could be optimized than a Python-wrapped one.

### How?

First, we'll change that RNA property to a vanilla *Transform Channel* property, and eliminate the Python, like so:

[image: "Type" has been changed to "Average Value," and the type of "var" has been set to "Transform Channel." "X Location" and "World Space" are selected.]

Then, we need to get that polynomial effect. Click *<kbd>Add Modifier</kbd> <kbd>Generator</kbd>* and input the following settings:

[image: A "Polynomial Generator" modifier with the "Poly Order" set to 2 and the x-squared coefficient set to 0.4 (which is two-fifths).]

This will have the desired effect.