# Create Square Array

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have an object that I want to make a square array like a 3x3x3 cube. I want be able to change length and count for one axis and have all the other ones follow.

[image: 3d array]

[image]

Comment: What about using drivers?

Comment: never used drivers before. not even sure what they do.

Comment: A driver is a python expression that gets evaluated, which means it can return values depending on some condition - like what the offset of the first array modifier is. And what it returns is used for the second/third modifier as well. It would basically link the offsets of modifier 2 and 3 to the offset of modifier 1. Not sure how to set it up though :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with [*Drivers*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Graph/Drivers)

1. Right click on the *Count* of the second modifier and select *Add Driver*.

   [image]
2. In the header of the *Graph editor*, change the editor type to *Drivers*:

   [image]
3. In the *Properties region* (<kbd>N</kbd>) set the variable to *Single property*, and the object to the object with the array modifier which values you want to copy:

   [image]
4. Right click on the *Count* of the array modifier you want to make the driver equal to and select *Copy Data path*:

   [image]
5. In the graph editor, Paste the copied *data path* in the *Path* box:

   [image]
6. Set the type to *Scripted expression*, and put the variable you have created in the *Expression* box:

   [image]

   As mentioned by [Wchargin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/create-square-array/3273?noredirect=1#comment6267_3273), as an alternative to *scripted expression* you could use *Sum Values* or something similar. These will be considered "trusted" by the python security features.

## Security

Blender has some [python security](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Security) features that will prevent the execution of *scripted expression* drivers. You can configure the settings for this in *User Preferences > File*. (see [After updating to Blender 2.68 Driver Scripts are no longer automatically excecuted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/after-updating-to-blender-2-68-driver-scripts-are-no-longer-automatically-excecu))

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step guide gandalf3, it now works for me. Why it didn't before was simply that drivers are disabled by default and I missed the note about it (you can turn it on globally in the _User Preferences > File > Auto Run Python Scripts_. Here's my .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/24507

Comment: Instead of *Scripted Expression* just set it to *Average Value* (or *Sum Values*, etc.) to avoid the Python problem. RNA paths are considered trusted implicitly.

Comment: @WChargin Good point, added.