# Can I "link" values in modifiers?

Tags: modifiers

I have a couple of wave modifiers on a mesh.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, all the values in the modifier options are exactly the same, apart from Offset.

Is there a more convenient way of changing one value for all of the modifiers (e.g. increasing Speed) without manually doing it for each one?

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/create-square-array

Comment: @gandalf3, that actually does what I want. Thank you.