# reverse photogrametry

Tags: image

I am new to all 3D graphics and I am not sure If this is the correct place for this question. Kindly refer me to the correct place if I am wrong.

I want to automate a reverse action to photogrametry, that is, take a 3D '.obj'\'.ply' file and produce multiple images of it covering many directions. I need to take ~200 images per ~10 objects so I would much like not to manually capture the images. Is there a solution?

Again sorry if this is not the correct forum.

Comment: so you want to take a 3D object in blender and render out about 200 different views of it? Yes that is very possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a camera animation orbiting around your object:

[How can I animate the camera in a perfect circular rotation around a fixed position?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/how-can-i-animate-the-camera-in-a-perfect-circular-rotation-around-a-fixed-posit)

You can also easily vary the height of the camera when it has *TrackTo* constraint. This animation should have as many frames as you want images.

Render this animation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>) as image frames: [Output options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/output.html#output-panel), see [Workflow > Frame Sequence](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/animations.html#workflow)